# Can’t use an existing Target Group when creating a new AWS ECS Service

Tags: amazon-ecs, aws-application-load-balancer

I’m trying to create a new ECS Service on an Application Load Balancer. When I get to the step to add the container to the Load Balancer I don’t have an option to use an existing Target Group (see image). Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks for your help.

[image]

Comment: is your existing target group attached with any load balancer?

Comment: you can only choose existing target group if it's not defined by ECS, but created by you and also attached with same LB that you are trying to integrate here

Comment: No the target group is not already attached to a Load Balancer.

Comment: So you are saying the target group must be created and attached to the Load Balancer I'm trying to use for the service?

Comment: If so that is what I did and it still requires me to create a new target group.

Comment: I solved it. The issue was the target group had to be set to ip not instance.

Answer (score 2):

The target group you created needs to be linked to your load balancer